# Login screen not showing up after waking from suspend, desktop showing with no interaction (xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, laptop, login-screen

[xfce version 4.16 on ubuntu 22.04]
I have been having an issue with the login screen not showing up ever since I have installed xubuntu.

After opening the laptop lid, the system wakes up from suspend and goes directly to the desktop. I cannot interact with anything, but notifications still show up. If I type my password and hit enter (there is no indication that I am doing so), it unlocks and lets me interact with the desktop.

If the computer falls asleep and is woken up after being left alone with the lid open, the login screen shows up just fine. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Having a version in the question could be helpful. Please EDIT the question and add this info.

Comment: Have you many displays ? What returns command `xrandr -q` ?